# New Android developer seeking guidance for structuring app

Tags: android

I am a new to developing for Android and have been reading up and researching in order to become more familiar with the platform.  My programming knowledge is moderate I have experience with C++ and a fairly proficient with Actionscript 3.0. I picked up programming primary to work on game development but come from a more artistic/design background.

I have a relatively simple idea for an app that I want to approach from the most practical way possible seeing how it’s my first attempt.  Essentially the core functionality of the app will be drawing information I will be getting from an ephemeris chart.  At a certain time in the day which is based on the data from the chart I want to change an image/display information based on that day. I am trying to wrap my head around the best possible way to do this.  Also I would like to give the user an option of having a notification of some kind when the change occurs, but that is something I have come across in terms of basic implementation.

So my question is if you were to approach setting something like this up how would you?  What I am not sure about is setting up a time element so the application knows when to change the image/data to display.
If you took the time to even read this I really appreciate it.
Wade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on where/when/how this image is displayed. I will assume that the image is shown in a *normal* `Activity`:

Look into using the `AlarmManager` to set alarms. These alarms could start a `Service` that changes the image source (perhaps updating a db entry of the image resource or filename). Once the work is complete in the `Service`, send a `Broadcast` (or `StickyBroadcast`) with the results in a `Bundle` using `Intent.putExtra()`. You could also set the status bar notification at this point using the `NotificationManager`. The `PendingIntent` of the `Notification` should be the `Activity` that shows the image.

Check out the "Alarm" and "Notification" sections of the [APIDemos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/index.html) (`/samples/android-8/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app`)

**UPDATE:** A more robust Alarm system is Mark Murphy's `WakefulIntentService` found [here](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful).

Then, register a `BroadcastReceiver` in that `Activity`, listening for the `Broadcast` `Intent` that you set in the `Service`. This will listen for when the service completes. If you use a `StickyBroadcast` in your `Service`, the data will be cached, making it available when the `Activity` comes to the front of the stack. Otherwise, you will need to persist the data (in an SQLite db or `SharedPrefernces`) and use a timestamp.

**UPDATE** - Demonstrate persistent data storage:

A great place to start with learning SQLite is the [Android Note Pad demo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html). This will teach you many of the key aspects of Android including life-cycles, `ContentProviders` (db wrappers), and using Android `Views` (widgets).

The alternative I mentioned is using the Application's default `SharedPreferences`. A simple example of usage is this:

```
String imageUri = null;
long timestamp = 0;
final String currentImage = "current_image";
final String lastTimestamp = "last_timestamp"

// Access the default SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences preferences = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
// The SharedPreferences editor - must use commit() to submit changes
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

// Get the current image URI
if (preferences.contains(currentImage) {
    imageUri = preferences.getString(currentImage, null);
}
// Get the last timestamp
if (preferences.contains(lastTimestamp) {
    timestamp = preferences.getLong(lastTimestamp, 0);
} 

// To set the SharedPreferences
editor.putString(currentImage, imageUri);
editor.putLong(lastTimestamp, timestamp);
editor.commit();
```

Hope I understand you correctly, and that this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paul.  I am pretty sure I'm following your breakdown. I will look into the alarm and notification sections as you advised.  Something Id like to trouble you to elaborate on is persisting the data and using a timestamp.